# How Can i Bulkify my below trigger so that it can handle more than 1 record

Tags: trigger, bulkification

```
trigger AttachmentBeforeInsert on Attachment (before insert) {
    System.debug('Before insertINg:');
    Set<Id> legacyJds = new Set<id>();
    Map<Id,Id> legacyIdMap = new Map<Id,Id>();


    for(Attachment attach : trigger.new){
        legacyJds.add(attach.ParentId);
    }
    for(Account acc : [select id,Legacy_SFDC_id__c  from Account where Legacy_SFDC_id__c in :legacyJds]){
        legacyIdMap.put(acc.Legacy_SFDC_id__c,acc.id);
    }
    for(Event evnt : [select id,Legacy_SFDC_id__c  from Event where Legacy_SFDC_id__c in :legacyJds]){
        legacyIdMap.put(evnt.Legacy_SFDC_id__c,evnt.id);
    }
    for(Opportunity opp : [select id,Legacy_SFDC_id__c  from opportunity where Legacy_SFDC_id__c in :legacyJds]){
        legacyIdMap.put(opp.Legacy_SFDC_id__c,opp.id);
    }
    for(contact ct : [select id,Legacy_SFDC_Id__c  from contact where Legacy_SFDC_Id__c in :legacyJds]){
        legacyIdMap.put(ct.Legacy_SFDC_Id__c,ct.id);
    }
    for(Lead ld : [select id,Legacy_SFDC_Id__c  from Lead where Legacy_SFDC_Id__c in :legacyJds]){
        legacyIdMap.put(ld.Legacy_SFDC_Id__c,ld.id);
    }
    for(Task task : [select id,Legacy_SFDC_id__c  from task where Legacy_SFDC_id__c in :legacyJds]){
        legacyIdMap.put(task.Legacy_SFDC_id__c,task.id);
    }
    for(Campaign cmp : [select id,Legacy_SFDC_id__c  from Campaign where Legacy_SFDC_id__c in :legacyJds]){
        legacyIdMap.put(cmp.Legacy_SFDC_id__c,cmp.id);
    }
    for(Credit__c crd : [select id,Legacy_SFDC_id__c  from Credit__c where Legacy_SFDC_id__c in :legacyJds]){
        legacyIdMap.put(crd.Legacy_SFDC_id__c,crd.id);
    }
    for(AtRisk__c atrisk : [select id,Legacy_SFDC_id__c  from AtRisk__c where Legacy_SFDC_id__c in :legacyJds]){
        legacyIdMap.put(atrisk.Legacy_SFDC_id__c,atrisk.id);
    }
    for(RFP__c rpf : [select id,Legacy_SFDC_id__c  from RFP__c where Legacy_SFDC_id__c in :legacyJds]){
        legacyIdMap.put(rpf.Legacy_SFDC_id__c,rpf.id);
    }
    for(Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c qp : [select id,Legacy_SFDC_id__c  from Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c where Legacy_SFDC_id__c in :legacyJds]){
        legacyIdMap.put(qp.Legacy_SFDC_id__c,qp.id);
    }
    for(Apttus__APTS_Template__c temp : [select id,Legacy_SFDC_id__c  from Apttus__APTS_Template__c where Legacy_SFDC_id__c in :legacyJds]){
        legacyIdMap.put(temp.Legacy_SFDC_id__c,temp.id);
    }
    System.debug('legacyIdMap:'+legacyIdMap);
    for(Attachment attach : trigger.new){
        if(legacyIdMap.containsKey(attach.ParentId))
            attach.ParentId = legacyIdMap.get(attach.ParentId);
    }
    /**** BEGIN --- Do not allow more than one attachement for contract Document ***/
    for(Attachment attach : trigger.new){
        String parentobjid = attach.ParentId;
        if (parentobjid.startsWith('a4L') ) {
          List <Attachment> contractDocsAtt = [select Id from Attachment  where ParentId = :parentobjid ];
          if (contractDocsAtt.size() >= 1)
          {
              trigger.new[0].addError('Cannot attach more than one attachment per Contract Document ');
          }

        }
    }
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? Please have an update in your question?

Comment: I want to bulkify this trigger as it is running into 101 soql error and hitting the governor limits.

Answer (score 4):

At the end of your code, you appear to be doing a query for each Attachment to find out how many Attachments the parent object of each Attachment has. Aggregate queries can do that sort of counting - see e.g. [Aggregate Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.214.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions.htm?search_text=count).

In that logic you filter by key prefix of 'a4L' so it looks like you are only interested in one parent SObjectType; presume the multiple queries earlier in the code have a different purpose. It would probably make sense to do a once off data-migration rather than adding a dozen queries every time an Attachment is inserted.

So the trigger code could be something like this (that I haven't tested):

```
Attachments[] attachments = new Attachment[] {};
for (Attachment a : Trigger.new) {
    if (a.ParentId.startsWith('a4L')) attachments.add(a);
}

if (attachments.size() > 0) {
    Set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (AggregateResult ar : [
            select ParentId p, COUNT(Id) c
            from Attachment
            where Id in :attachments
            group by ParentId
            ]) {
        Id parentId = (Id) ar.get('p');
        Integer c = (Integer) ar.get('c');
        if (c > 1) parentIds.add(parentId);
    }
    if (parentIds.size() > 0) {
        for (Attachment a : Trigger.new) {
            if (parentIds.contains(a.ParentId)) {
                a.addError('Cannot attach ...');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When adding triggers to a standard object, take great care as most orgs contain multiple apps and multiple groups of users. So while a trigger might be added just for one app or group of users, it can break (or slow down) all apps and block the work of all groups of users.

Comment: A simple one-liner: `Set<Id> tooManyAttachIds = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>(
[SELECT ParentId Id, COUNT(Id) FROM Attachment WHERE Id = :attachments GROUP BY ParentId HAVING COUNT(Id) > 1]).keySet()`. It avoids the `if(c > 1)` bit entirely. And the initial for loop.

Comment: @sfdcfox Please post as an answer; I've never used the `HAVING` and great to see a good example.